# Multiple filters in Room database android

Tags: android, android-room

I want to query with multiple filters using room database. For example

```
 @Query("SELECT SUM(total_amount) as total FROM settlement_table where date_and_time>=:fromDate and date_and_time<=:toDate and orderType=:orderType and user_id=:user_id")
    fun getSettlementDataTotalAmountOrderTypeUserId(fromDate: Long, toDate: Long,orderType:Int?,user_id: String?): ModelSum
```

I have a situation when `user_id` and `orderType` is null. some time either one is null. But  when I pass null value it return no data
How can I acheive filter with single query?

Comment: Hi, can please explain bit more as i am not able to find order_id  in your query.

Comment: hi.. i mean orderType.. my mistake. i will edit question

Comment: Ok, any of the given data can be null but you should have the result ri8 ?

Comment: yes...  orderType and  user_id can be null. but i still need to have results. i want to avoid ordertype and user_id when it is null.  but still need results

Comment: Yes adding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to valid null then you need do some modifications.

```
@Entity(tableName = "settlement_table")
data class Settlement(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") val user_id: String? = "-1",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "orderType") val longitude: Int? = -1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_amount") val total_amount: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_and_time") val date_and_time: Long
)
```

Table where you have set default values when you insert values as null.
So, now your query will be

```
  @Query("SELECT SUM(total_amount) as total FROM settlement_table where date_and_time>=:fromDate and date_and_time<=:toDate and orderType=:orderType and user_id=:user_id")
    fun getSettlementDataTotalAmountOrderTypeUserId(
        fromDate: Long,
        toDate: Long,
        orderType: Int? = -1,
        user_id: String? = "-1"
    ): ModelSum
```

Here you can see we set default values while insert to -1 and while performing query also we using the same values if that `orderType` & `user_id` found null

**EDIT**

then there is simple thing you need to do ,
You need to create three method with same name with different params, like Method overloading.
**Method 1 : With Both not null**

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(total_amount) as total FROM settlement_table where date_and_time>=:fromDate and date_and_time<=:toDate and orderType=:orderType and user_id=:user_id")
        fun getSettlementDataTotalAmountOrderTypeUserId(
            fromDate: Long,
            toDate: Long,
            orderType: Int,
            user_id: String
        ): ModelSum
```

**Method 2 : With orderType is null**

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(total_amount) as total FROM settlement_table where date_and_time>=:fromDate and date_and_time<=:toDate and user_id=:user_id")
        fun getSettlementDataTotalAmountOrderTypeUserId(
            fromDate: Long,
            toDate: Long,         
            user_id: String
        ): ModelSum
```

**Method 2 : With user_id is null**

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(total_amount) as total FROM settlement_table where date_and_time>=:fromDate and date_and_time<=:toDate and orderType=:orderType")
        fun getSettlementDataTotalAmountOrderTypeUserId(
            fromDate: Long,
            toDate: Long,         
            orderType: Int
        ): ModelSum
```

So when calling this method you need make conditions

```
if(orderType!=null && user_id!=null)    {
// Call method 1
}else if(user_id!=null)    {
// Call method 2
}else if(orderType!=null)    {
// Call method 3
}
```

Hope it will helps you with your issue

Comment: in database user_id and ordertype have values as mandatory field. So it doesn't need to change to -1 for default.   I am passing null values to query .So it is not returning any data